# Using STDIN with degrib

Tags: linux

We are using the latest version of degrib (2.02) http://www.nws.noaa.gov/mdl/degrib/tutorial.php with some grib files but I am having a hard time getting the "Input on stdin" feature to work. See "-in" #3: http://www.nws.noaa.gov/mdl/degrib/txtview.php?file=degrib.txt&dir=base

I am unable to get this to work doing something like `cat gribfile.bin | degrib -opt1 -opt2 -etc` From what I could tell, that should work, but it complains of "-opt1" not being a valid file (still trying to read the first arg). Has anyone gotten this to work?

The end goal is to be able to do a database probe (-DP) from streams, not sure if that will be possible though.

Thanks,

-Seth

Comment: I don't believe you can use stdin for the input file. I believe you need to specify a file with the `-in` parameter. I'm also using v2.02.